# Eclipse 2022-06 for Java EE: class oracle.eclipse.tools.common.util.classloader.jarnocache.JarProtocolHandlerWithoutLeak

Tags: java, eclipse

Error

[image]

```
An internal error occurred during: "Updating classloader".
superclass access check failed: class oracle.eclipse.tools.common.util.classloader.jarnocache.JarProtocolHandlerWithoutLeak (in unnamed module @0x2704c8cb) cannot access class sun.net.www.protocol.jar.Handler (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.net.www.protocol.jar to unnamed module @0x2704c8cb
```

Comment: Are you upgrading from 2022-03 to 2022-06 or directly installing 2022-06?

Comment: I don't know where that Oracle class comes from but it is trying to do something that the Java 17 included in most Eclipse 2022-06 downloads will not allow. Maybe using Java 11 would work.

Comment: Adding oracle web logic tools from marketplace creates this same error for me too. Uninstall will restore previous state but than i cant use the server.

Comment: I would guess that the driver is to old for handling Java modules (introduced JDK 9).  Up to JDK 11 or something that would work because Java modules had some backward compatibility hacks, but JDK 17 have rightfully so removed that hack.  I might miss some details though.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Spring Tool Suite 4.14.1.RELEASE** (based on *Eclipse 2022-03*), the problem started when installing the **oracle-database-tools** plugin. After uninstalling it, the error no longer occurred. If you have an oracle plugin installed that you no longer need, maybe uninstalling it can help.

Comment: Might need to install the old jar that doesn't support module with a newer driver that supports Java modules.  Yes, modules are good thing, but breaks code that doesn't use modules, which all Java programs and libraries since JDK 9 should use.

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue using Java 17 on eclipse 03-2023. While setting up JBOSS EAP 8.0 got same screen. I resolved by restarting and creating new workspace!